# UseNavigate hook does not re-render components. Can I force it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using the useNavigate hook in my component. This is a simplification of my code.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function UpdateData() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function update() {
    //code to update my database
    navigate("/");
  }
 update();

  return ...some JSX code...;
}

export default UpdateData;
```

So I am updating my database, and once that is done I want to navigate to my homepage with navigate("/").

The homepage component retrieves data from the database and displays them. But the problem is that once I navigate to the homepage ("/"), it does not show the updated data. It shows the data before the update.

So I press F5 to re-render the component and then only the component retrieves the updated data.

How can I retrieve the data (re-render the homepage component) without pressing the F5 button?

Comment: do not call `update();` directly it should be passed to a **useEffect**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am having the exact same problem exactly as you describe.

Comment: @LNX Did you got any solution for this ?  I am also facing this issue

Comment: Yes I did solve it, and my case may not apply to yours.  In my app, Homepage.js is a child component of App.js.  What I did was create a callback function in the parent component and passed it as a prop to the child component that does the database update.  If the database update succeeds, I call the callback function with props.editSuccess() before calling navigate("/").  This way, by the time the page redirects to the homepage, my callback function is already updating the homepage's state higher up in App.js.  That state object is passed to Homepage.js as a prop.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and adding `navigate(0);` after `navigate("/");` worked for me.
Here's how it should look like:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
function UpdateData() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function update() {
    //code to update my database
    navigate("/");
    navigate(0);
  }
 update();

  return ...some JSX code...;
}

export default UpdateData;
```

Hopefully it works for everybody else! **Note: use it with caution!**

Comment: Maybe explain what navigate(0) does?